# Why would Apache log different response sizes for the same url?

Tags: linux, cache, apache2, log-files, web-crawler

I noticed a couple (ostensibly-)harmless log entries, and--I'm admittedly overthinking this by a mile--got curious about Apache2 response sizes.

This Ukranian crawler † hit my web daemon, two seconds later requesting a duplicate.  Apache2 replied with 41,298 bytes and then 41,244.

My question is:

Why are the response sizes different--*by only 54 bytes*--for the same URL?

I have not customized Apache's default cache declarations.  If something *were* cached, I'd expect a difference near 100% of the requested content (or at least more than 0.01%).

All I can think of is a small file--a tiny GIF or .css file?--that inexplicably is the only component that's cached, but a search for files that size produced no results:

`find . -type f -size -55c -size +53c`

...searching 53 or 55 finds small .GIF files, and widening by several bytes yields a lot more.  Expanding this <s>assumption</s> guess, the "missing" response data may be a file ***and*** its respective path--but that seems counter to how I thought caching works.

What am I seeing here?

---

ANCILLARY

They're the only two entries:

```
# grep -r 46.119.77.28 /var/log
/var/log/apache2/example.com-access.log:46.119.77.28 - - [26/Apr/2020:19:56:20 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 41298 "http://www.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/54.0.2952.64 (Edition Yx)"
/var/log/apache2/example.com-access.log:46.119.77.28 - - [26/Apr/2020:19:56:22 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 41244 "http://www.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/54.0.2952.64 (Edition Yx)"
```

† Around nine hours earlier it hit one of my other servers, and shortly afterward yet another.  While not actively seeking vulns, it's clearly crawling the web, so I've blocked it out of principle--no immediate or planned need to be indexed outside the US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `wireshark` or `tcpdump` to capture the network traffic. Should be easy enough to look at both responses and find the difference.

It's probably response headers changing slightly. Some headers vary with clients and time.

Comment: Wireshark is a good idea.  Except I won't know if/when it'll happen again.

Comment: I forget that I can't hit [enter] in a comment.  This guy hit the server two seconds apart and (I just confirmed what eyeballs were pretty sure) the same user agent.  That said, I think your headers idea is likely what's happened here.